# I get an error 3075 (Missing operator) when trying to run an sql. update query

Tags: sql, vba, excel

The VBA code is:

```
''sql1 = "select  InvoiceCNotes.[docsetamount] ,InvoiceCNotes.[docsetamount] + AllocationsTEMP.[paidamount] from AllocationsTEMP inner join  InvoiceCNotes on AllocationsTEMP.Docnumber = InvoiceCNotes.Docnumber where InvoiceCNotes.[docnumber] = AllocationsTEMP.[docnumber] AND AllocationsTEMP.[paidamount] <> 0"

sqlline = sql1

DoCmd.RunSQL sql1
```

The code as displayed in sqlline above, is as follows:

```
Update InvoiceCNotes 
set InvoiceCNotes.[docsetamount] = InvoiceCNotes.[docsetamount] + AllocationsTEMP.[paidamount] 
from AllocationsTEMP inner join  InvoiceCNotes 
    on AllocationsTEMP.Docnumber = InvoiceCNotes.Docnumber 
where InvoiceCNotes.[docnumber] = AllocationsTEMP.[docnumber] 
    AND AllocationsTEMP.[paidamount] <> 0
```

I have looked at other questions here regarding the same error, but still I am missing something.

From previous questions, I added the table names, and bracketed the field names. 
I checked the table specs to see that `docsetamount` and `paidamount` are both defined as [NUMBER,double,fixed,2], the two `docnumbers` are both long integers, and `paidamount` is also NUMBER,double,fixed,2

Now I am possibly staring into the problem and not noticing my error, as I have developed quite a few apps in Access over the past five years (since retirement I should add) so I must have done something wrong.

Do you notice the mistake?

Comment: Could you post the **actual** code that is causing the error? The first is a SELECT query string that you say is coming out as an UPDATE query string somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The `UPDATE t1 SET t1.f=foo FROM t1 JOIN t2` syntax with the `FROM` is from Sql Server.

In Access SQL you put the JOIN in the first clause, like this:

```
UPDATE InvoiceCNotes INNER JOIN AllocationsTEMP 
  ON InvoiceCNotes.Docnumber = AllocationsTEMP.Docnumber
SET InvoiceCNotes.[docsetamount] = InvoiceCNotes.[docsetamount] + AllocationsTEMP.[paidamount] 
WHERE AllocationsTEMP.[paidamount] <> 0
```

`where InvoiceCNotes.[docnumber] = AllocationsTEMP.[docnumber]` is superfluous because it's already in the JOIN condition.

Comment: Thanks - I found that somewhere else, and commented before seeing your reply.
I'm afraid I really missed this one - sometimes a man can feel pretty daft - for me this is one of those times.

Comment: @CorrievanRooyen: That's ok, things like this happen. You can accept the answer to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a totally different syntax - and it works just fine.
Maybe my original source was wrong, as I did exactly hat it said.

My new syntax for the update is:

```
UPDATE InvoiceCNotes INNER JOIN AllocationsTEMP 
    ON InvoiceCNotes.Docnumber = AllocationsTEMP.Docnumber 
SET InvoiceCNotes.docsetamount = InvoiceCNotes.[docsetamount]+AllocationsTEMP.[paidamount] 
WHERE (((InvoiceCNotes.docnumber)=[AllocationsTEMP].[docnumber]) 
  AND ((AllocationsTEMP.paidamount)<>False))
```

Maybe this question should just be removed - it will cause confusion rather than to be helpful. I can't do that, or I would.

Apologies to whoever might have tried to help - and thanks for the effort.

This is now SOLVED

Comment: Just a note: the `WHERE InvoiceCNotes.docnumber=[AllocationsTEMP].[docnumber]` clause is still superfluous.